# Mysql Trigger com mais de um cursor

Tags: mysql, trigger, cursor

Tenho uma Trigger onde possuo 3 cursores, porém ela só executa corretamente um deles(soma_pontuacao_cursor), os outros dois são executados de forma errada, eu já tentei com três loops separados, e também não funcionou. A minha percepção diz que é algo em relação com o Handler, ele executa um dos cursores e quando completa este ele sai do loop ignorando os outros, enfim não tenho certeza, só uma impressão.
Procuro além de uma resolução uma explicação.
Segue a trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER upd_pontuacao_equipes AFTER UPDATE ON grande_premio
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE pfp_equipe_ficticia_id INTEGER;
DECLARE pfp_cursor_done INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE piloto_Id INTEGER DEFAULT 0;    
DECLARE piloto_Id1 INTEGER DEFAULT 0;   

DECLARE equipe_Id INTEGER DEFAULT 0; 
DECLARE soma_pontuacao_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT c.pilotoId FROM corrida c
    WHERE c.gpId=NEW.id;
DECLARE soma_posicoes_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT er.id,c.pilotoId FROM corrida c
    INNER JOIN pilotos p ON c.pilotoId=p.id
    INNER JOIN equipes_reais er ON p.equipeId=er.id;
DECLARE pfp_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT efp.equipeId
    FROM equipe_ficticia ef
    INNER JOIN equipe_ficticia_pilotos efp ON efp.equipeId = ef.id
    INNER JOIN pilotos p ON efp.pilotoId=p.id
    INNER JOIN pontuacao_ficticia_piloto pfp ON p.id=pfp.pilotoId
    WHERE pfp.gpId = NEW.id GROUP BY ef.id
    FOR UPDATE;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET pfp_cursor_done = 1;

IF NEW.ativo = 'c' THEN
BEGIN
    OPEN pfp_cursor;
    OPEN soma_pontuacao_cursor;
    OPEN soma_posicoes_cursor;              
    -- cursor 1
    soma_posicoes_cursor_loop:LOOP
    FETCH soma_posicoes_cursor INTO equipe_Id,piloto_Id1;
    FETCH soma_pontuacao_cursor INTO piloto_Id;     
    FETCH pfp_cursor INTO pfp_equipe_ficticia_id;
    IF pfp_cursor_done = 1 THEN
            LEAVE soma_posicoes_cursor_loop;
        END IF;

    SELECT SUM(posicao) INTO @sp FROM corrida WHERE pilotoId=piloto_Id1 AND gpId=NEW.id;
    SELECT SUM(posicoes) INTO @p FROM equipes_reais WHERE id=equipe_Id;

    UPDATE equipes_reais SET posicoes=@sp+@p WHERE id=equipe_Id;    

    -- cursor 2        

    SELECT SUM(pfp.pontuacao_ficticia) into @a FROM pontuacao_ficticia_piloto pfp
    INNER JOIN pilotos p ON pfp.pilotoId=p.id
    INNER JOIN equipe_ficticia_pilotos efp ON p.id=efp.pilotoId
    WHERE pfp.gpId=NEW.id AND efp.equipeId=pfp_equipe_ficticia_id;

    UPDATE equipe_ficticia          
    SET pontuacao_ficticia = @a WHERE id = pfp_equipe_ficticia_id; 
    -- cursor 3
    SELECT SUM(pontuacao_ficticia) INTO @c FROM corrida WHERE pilotoId=piloto_Id AND gpId=NEW.id;
    SELECT SUM(pontuacao_ficticia) INTO @q FROM qualify WHERE pilotoId=piloto_Id AND gpId=NEW.id;

     UPDATE pontuacao_ficticia_piloto          
        SET pontuacao_ficticia = @c+@q WHERE pilotoId=piloto_Id AND gpId=NEW.id;
    END LOOP;     
    CLOSE soma_posicoes_cursor;
    CLOSE pfp_cursor;
    CLOSE soma_pontuacao_cursor;

END;
END IF;

END; $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Qual a ideia de usar 3 cursores? será a de executar loops um dentro do outro?

Comment: Não, executá-los separadamente. No exemplo estão dentro do mesmo loop, por causa de um exemplo que vi no site do MySQL.

Comment: Você que executar um apos o outro, dentro da mesma TRIGGER ?

Comment: Exatamente isso.